# adjust table view size in iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iphone-5

I have created an universal app and i run it in iphone 5 simulator i.e. iphone retina 4. All is working fine but a table view size is not appropriate.Actually, i have that table view completely above an image view. When i run in iphone retina 4, the image sets itself according to the retina 4 display but the table view height extends beyond that image view. I have set the table view size as 160 in the inspector window and when i print that in log, it says 248.0000.
I am unable to figure out where the problem is. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Check for Auto Resizing]

You can resize view by this.

And please uncheck 'Use Autolayout' Option. bcoz it'll restrict you with specific margins.

Hopefully it works.

Comment: I have tried this. setting the height of table view in retina 4 automatically changes height of that in retina 3.5

Comment: Set Size of ViewController as 'Inferred'

Comment: I have set the size of view controller as 'Inferred' and set the size of table view as 160. I run the project as retina 4 simulator, it still displays table view size as 248 and table view is extending beyond the background image view.

Comment: What do you want ? 160 fixed? Then remove two arrows between small rectangle.

Comment: upvote the answer & you can suggest to others for helping in this kind of issue..:)